# Meteor upsert returns Error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am getting an error when using upsert in my Meteor application. I have a collection with permissions...

```
Parts = new Mongo.Collection('parts');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Parts.allow({
    insert : function () {
      return true;
    },
    update : function () {
      return true;
    },
    remove : function () {
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

and an upsert method that checks if a document with "partName" has already been created.

```
Meteor.call( 'partsUpsert', partName, content );

Meteor.methods({
    partsUpsert: function (partName, content) {
        Parts.upsert(
            check(content, Number),
            check(partName, String),
            {name: partName},
            { 
                $set: {vertices: content}
            }
        );
    }
});
```

If it hasn't been created, it should insert a new document into the database. But I keep getting the server error `Exception while invoking method 'partsUpsert' Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.`

I have tried modifying the code but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checks are part of the method, not the `upsert`. Try this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  partsUpsert: function (partName, content) {
    check(content, Number);
    check(partName, String);

    return Parts.upsert({name: partName}, {$set: {vertices: content}});
  }
});
```